# Core Graphics in Cocoa OS X: Getting raw data from CGImageRef inconsistency?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, cocoa, core-graphics

I found 2 methods of getting raw data from CGImageRef:

First method:

```
 unsigned char *CGImageCopyRawData(CGImageRef image, size_t *rawDataLength) {

    CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(image);
    CFDataRef data = CGDataProviderCopyData(dataProvider);
    if(rawDataLength) *rawDataLength = (size_t) CFDataGetLength(data);
    CFRelease(dataProvider);
    CFRelease(data); 
    return CFDataGetBytePtr(data);
}
```

Second method:

```
static unsigned char *CGImageCopyPixelData(CGImageRef image, CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace, uint32_t bitmap_info, size_t *pixelDataLength) {

    unsigned char *pixelData = 0;

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(image);

    // allocate image pixel components array, where each component takes one byte (unsigned char)
    size_t dataLength = width*height*COMPONENTS_PER_PIXEL*BYTES_PER_COMPONENT;
    pixelData = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * (dataLength));
    if(pixelData == 0) {
        *pixelDataLength = 0;
        return 0;
    }

    // draw image using core graphics context in frame buffer
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelData, width, height, BITS_PER_COMPONENT,
                                                 COMPONENTS_PER_PIXEL * width, colorSpace, bitmap_info);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height), image);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    if(pixelDataLength) *pixelDataLength = dataLength;
    return pixelData;
}
```

I heard that first method returns raw data as they are without guarantying colorspace, number of components per pixel, number of bits per component, order of bytes Big-endian, Little-endian.

But taking into account that the **CGImageRef** is just screenshot from `CGDisplayCreateImage(mainDisplayId)` I can assume that this will be bitmapMask `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little`.

But this to methods return different results and it isn't different bytes ordering but values a little different but similar in colours when checking hexadecimal colours in graphical programs like Adobe Photoshop:

First output is:

```
[F8 E0 D2 FF] [F8 E0 D2 FF] [F8 E0 D2 FF] [F8 E0 D2 FF] [F8 E1 D2 FF] [F8 E1 D2 FF] [F8 E1 D2 FF] [F8 E1 D2 FF] [F8 E1 D2 FF] [F8 E1 D2 FF] [F8 E1 D2 FF]...
```

Second output is:

```
[F7 E1 D4 FF] [F7 E1 D4 FF] [F7 E1 D4 FF] [F7 E1 D4 FF] [F7 E2 D4 FF] [F7 E2 D4 FF] [F7 E2 D4 FF] [F7 E2 D4 FF] [F7 E2 D4 FF] [F7 E2 D4 FF] [F7 E2 D4 FF] [F7 E2 D4 FF]...
```

So as you see there is just a little difference like some bit set or not set, maybe something with signed/unsigned char in C?

Comment: 1. Your first code sample contains memory leak. 2. Your second code sample returns `CGImageRef`, not raw data pointer.

Comment: Ok I copied wrong method :) I have updated now.